# Maven project building fails at test-compile stage with NoClassDefFoundError and others

Tags: java, maven, java-8

I'm totally lost with the unhelpful Maven trace. `mvn compile` succeeds like a charm but with `mvn package`, the tests (of this particular quickstart tutorial) fail with `NoClassDefFoundError`, `NoSuchMethodError` at `test-compile` stage (with `-DskipTests=true` option emitting that stage it works successfully) of the Maven build process. Also, projects fails at runtime with those errors.

I have this problem in my own project, and to go through the proper mvn install and project initialization from an archetype I ended up to go through the process with a bear bone tutorial.

When compiled and packaged on a remote machine (OS is Ubuntu 16.04, local is OS X), it packages and compiles normally. With the local machine, not.

trace:

```
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building first-dataflow 0.1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ first-dataflow ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/user/projects/personal/first-dataflow/src/main/resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ first-dataflow ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ first-dataflow ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/user/projects/personal/first-dataflow/src/test/resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ first-dataflow ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.20:test (default-test) @ first-dataflow ---
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running com.example.WordCountTest
[ERROR] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.002 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.example.WordCountTest
[ERROR] testCountWords(com.example.WordCountTest)  Time elapsed: 0.002 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.requiresPropertyOrdering()Z
    at com.example.WordCountTest.<init>(WordCountTest.java:72)

[ERROR] testExtractWordsFn(com.example.WordCountTest)  Time elapsed: 0.002 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.beam.sdk.testing.TestPipeline
    at com.example.WordCountTest.<init>(WordCountTest.java:72)

[INFO] Running com.example.DebuggingWordCountTest
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.098 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.example.DebuggingWordCountTest
[ERROR] testDebuggingWordCount(com.example.DebuggingWordCountTest)  Time elapsed: 0.098 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.beam.sdk.testing.TestPipeline
    at com.example.DebuggingWordCountTest.testDebuggingWordCount(DebuggingWordCountTest.java:47)

[INFO]
[INFO] Results:
[INFO]
[ERROR] Errors:
[ERROR]   DebuggingWordCountTest.testDebuggingWordCount:47 NoClassDefFound Could not ini...
[ERROR]   WordCountTest.<init>:72 » NoSuchMethod com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory....
[ERROR]   WordCountTest.<init>:72 NoClassDefFound Could not initialize class org.apache....
[INFO]
[ERROR] Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 3, Skipped: 0
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.948 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-06-24T22:40:00+03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 17M/437M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.20:test (default-test) on project first-dataflow: There are test failures.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Please refer to /Users/user/projects/personal/first-dataflow/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date]-jvmRun[N].dump, [date].dumpstream and [date]-jvmRun[N].dumpstream.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ~ Copyright (C) 2017 Google Inc.
  ~
  ~ Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
  ~ use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of
  ~ the License at
  ~
  ~ http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
  ~
  ~ Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  ~ distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT
  ~ WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the
  ~ License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations under
  ~ the License.
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~-->
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>first-dataflow</artifactId>
  <version>0.1</version>

  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <surefire-plugin.version>2.20</surefire-plugin.version>
  </properties>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>ossrh.snapshots</id>
      <name>Sonatype OSS Repository Hosting</name>
      <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
      <releases>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <parallel>all</parallel>
          <threadCount>4</threadCount>
          <redirectTestOutputToFile>true</redirectTestOutputToFile>
        </configuration>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
            <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
            <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>

      <!-- Ensure that the Maven jar plugin runs before the Maven
        shade plugin by listing the plugin higher within the file. -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>

      <!--
        Configures `mvn package` to produce a bundled jar ("fat jar") for runners
        that require this for job submission to a cluster.
      -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <finalName>${project.artifactId}-bundled-${project.version}</finalName>
              <filters>
                <filter>
                  <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                  <excludes>
                    <exclude>META-INF/LICENSE</exclude>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                  </excludes>
                </filter>
              </filters>
              <transformers>
                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
              </transformers>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>

    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
          <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.4.0</version>
          <configuration>
            <cleanupDaemonThreads>false</cleanupDaemonThreads>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- Adds a dependency on a specific version of the Dataflow SDK. -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.cloud.dataflow</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Dependencies below this line are specific dependencies needed by the examples code. -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
      <version>1.22.0</version>
      <exclusions>
        <!-- Exclude an old version of guava that is being pulled
             in by a transitive dependency of google-api-client -->
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
          <artifactId>guava-jdk5</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-api-services-bigquery</artifactId>
      <version>v2-rev295-1.22.0</version>
      <exclusions>
        <!-- Exclude an old version of guava that is being pulled
             in by a transitive dependency of google-api-client -->
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
          <artifactId>guava-jdk5</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-http-client</artifactId>
      <version>1.22.0</version>
      <exclusions>
        <!-- Exclude an old version of guava that is being pulled
             in by a transitive dependency of google-api-client -->
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
          <artifactId>guava-jdk5</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-api-services-pubsub</artifactId>
      <version>v1-rev10-1.22.0</version>
      <exclusions>
        <!-- Exclude an old version of guava that is being pulled
             in by a transitive dependency of google-api-client -->
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
          <artifactId>guava-jdk5</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
      <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
      <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
      <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
      <version>20.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Add slf4j API frontend binding with JUL backend -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.14</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.14</version>
      <!-- When loaded at runtime this will wire up slf4j to the JUL backend -->
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hamcrest and JUnit are required dependencies of PAssert,
         which is used in the main code of DebuggingWordCount example. -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
      <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
      <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

---

```
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_111.jdk/Contents/Home
$ echo $M2_HOME
/opt/maven
```

Edit: tutorial reference:
https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-java-maven

Dependency tree:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.example:first-dataflow:jar:0.1
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin is missing. @ line 79, column 15
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building first-dataflow 0.1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ first-dataflow ---
[INFO] com.example:first-dataflow:jar:0.1
[INFO] +- com.google.cloud.dataflow:google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all:jar:2.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-core:jar:2.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.8.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.8.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.8.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.avro:avro:jar:1.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.thoughtworks.paranamer:paranamer:jar:2.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.tukaani:xz:jar:1.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:jar:1.1.4-M3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-io-google-cloud-platform:jar:2.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-extensions-google-cloud-platform-core:jar:2.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.google.cloud.bigdataoss:gcsio:jar:1.4.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.google.apis:google-api-services-cloudresourcemanager:jar:v1-rev6-1.22.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-extensions-protobuf:jar:2.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.api.grpc:grpc-google-pubsub-v1:jar:0.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.google.api.grpc:grpc-google-iam-v1:jar:0.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.cloud.bigdataoss:util:jar:1.4.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.google.api-client:google-api-client-java6:jar:1.20.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.google.api-client:google-api-client-jackson2:jar:1.20.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-java6:jar:1.20.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.cloud.datastore:datastore-v1-proto-client:jar:1.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.google.http-client:google-http-client-protobuf:jar:1.20.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson:jar:1.20.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.cloud.datastore:datastore-v1-protos:jar:1.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.grpc:grpc-auth:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.grpc:grpc-core:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:jar:2.0.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.grpc:grpc-context:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.google.instrumentation:instrumentation-api:jar:0.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.grpc:grpc-netty:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.netty:netty-codec-http2:jar:4.1.8.Final:compile (version selected from constraint [4.1.8.Final,4.1.8.Final])
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- io.netty:netty-codec-http:jar:4.1.8.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- io.netty:netty-handler-proxy:jar:4.1.8.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- io.netty:netty-codec-socks:jar:4.1.8.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-handler:jar:4.1.8.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.1.8.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.1.8.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.1.8.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- io.netty:netty-resolver:jar:4.1.8.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- io.netty:netty-codec:jar:4.1.8.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.grpc:grpc-stub:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.grpc:grpc-all:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:jar:2.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- com.squareup.okio:okio:jar:1.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java-util:jar:3.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |     \- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.grpc:grpc-protobuf-lite:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- io.grpc:grpc-protobuf-nano:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- com.google.protobuf.nano:protobuf-javanano:jar:3.0.0-alpha-5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.cloud.bigtable:bigtable-protos:jar:0.9.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.cloud.bigtable:bigtable-client-core:jar:0.9.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.google.auth:google-auth-library-appengine:jar:0.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk:jar:1.9.34:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-core:jar:3.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.auth:google-auth-library-credentials:jar:0.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.auth:google-auth-library-oauth2-http:jar:0.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.api.grpc:grpc-google-common-protos:jar:0.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:3.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.netty:netty-tcnative-boringssl-static:jar:1.1.33.Fork26:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.beam:beam-runners-direct-java:jar:2.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.beam:beam-runners-google-cloud-dataflow-java:jar:2.0.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-common-runner-api:jar:2.0.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.google.apis:google-api-services-dataflow:jar:v1b3-rev196-1.22.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.google.apis:google-api-services-clouddebugger:jar:v2-rev8-1.22.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.google.apis:google-api-services-storage:jar:v1-rev71-1.22.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.api-client:google-api-client:jar:1.22.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client:jar:1.22.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson2:jar:1.22.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.apis:google-api-services-bigquery:jar:v2-rev295-1.22.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.http-client:google-http-client:jar:1.22.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:1.3.9:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.0.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.0.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.apis:google-api-services-pubsub:jar:v1-rev10-1.22.0:compile
[INFO] +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:20.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.14:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14:jar:1.7.14:runtime
[INFO] +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] \- junit:junit:jar:4.12:compile
[INFO]    \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.080 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-06-24T23:24:24+03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 18M/437M
[INFO] ------------------
```

Comment: what jar actually provides `com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory`? because I can't see it as a dependency in your `pom.xml`

Comment: `google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all` does

Comment: Yeah can be but the google-cloud-dataflow-java-dsk-all defines one but the best practice is to define the dependencies you are using directly in your pom file...The question is: Is this the correct version which is coming via transitive?

Comment: Tried to exclude it from dataflow depedency and added the three separate dependencies (with the same version, as version discrepancy between jackson dependencies was reason for `com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.requiresPropertyOrdering()Z` not found for other dependencies, not mine...)

Comment: do you have google cloud sdk installed (not sure if it is mandatory). Tried clean build? Can you try again with -X and paste the relevant infor?

Comment: This relates to `com.jackson.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory` somehow.  Version of jackson from dataflow is 2.8.8, and the method it's throwing `NoSuchMethodError` has been introduced in 2.3. iirc. And as said, the symptoms are related to runtime as build is a success w/o tests.

Comment: Reinstalled Java completely (which I installed from Oracle executable iirc) and installed it using `brew cask`, and now it's working. So there probably there was a dependency to some older jackson version, though I don't know how to find out non-project libs of java. Any idea?